# How can I use CSS to add a blank column between paired column groupings?

Tags: php, css, arrays, formatting, multiple-columns

I have the following code that displays a matrix of word counts  in three columns of five paired rows, each pair containing a word and a count (supplied by @Aiias here in stackoverflow). I added the  tags to alternate colors in the paired groupings. It now looks like this:

| word | count | word | count | word | count |
   | word | count | word | count | word | count |, etc.

I am struggling to add a variable-width blank SPACE between each paired column, as well as remove the border between 'word' and 'count' to look like this:

| word  count | SPACE | word  count | SPACE | word  count |
   | word  count | SPACE | word  count | SPACE | word  count |, etc.

Here's what I have:

```
function showWords($words) {
        $rows = array();
        $max_per_column = 5;
        $max_words = 15;
        $rows = array_pad($rows, $max_per_column, array());
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($words as $word => $item) {
            if ($count >= $max_words) {
                break;
            }
            array_push($rows[$count % $max_per_column], $word, $item);
            $count++;
        }           
        ?>

        <table id="table" class="table-list">
            <colgroup span="2">
                <col style="background: #CCFFCC;">
                <col style="background: #FFCCCC;">
            </colgroup>
            <colgroup span="2">
                <col style="background: #CCFFCC;">
                <col style="background: #FFCCCC;">
            </colgroup>
            <colgroup span="2">
                <col style="background: #CCFFCC;">
                <col style="background: #FFCCCC;">
            </colgroup>
          <tbody>
            <?php
              foreach ($rows as $cols) {
                echo '<tr><td>' . implode('</td><td>', $cols) . '</td></tr>';
              }
            ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>   
        <?            
    }
```

Here is the additional CSS:

```
#table {
   font-family: "Calibri", Sans-Serif;
   font-size: 11px;
   margin: 0px;
   width: auto;
   text-align: left;
   border-collapse: collapse; 
}
table.table-list {
   width: 36%;
   line-height: 1;
   text-align: left;
}
```

Thank you, kindly, in advance for your assistance. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the best I can come up with using only CSS modifications (JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zKRYM/2/):

```
td:nth-child(2n-1) {
    background: lightgreen;
    border-left: 2px solid blue;
}

td:nth-child(2n) {
    display: block;
    background: pink;
    margin-right: 30px;
    border-right: 2px solid blue;
}
```

I've use CSS pseudo-selectors to get every odd table element, add  a `border-left`, and then got ever even element and added `margin-right` for the spacing as well as the `border-right`.

Note that I've also removed the table headers and transferred the colors onto the `td` elements instead of keeping them on the `col` elements. This is because I've added margins, and I assume you want those to be white (not filled with color). Note that you can still keep your `col` and `colgroup`s, just remove the background colors.

Comment: thank you very much for your solution. It worked well enough that I was able to embed 'class="nth-child(2n-1)' into a loop structure and now separate out the paired columns with space and your color solution in external CSS but also now use a variable number of rows and paired columns. Awesome solution. Thanks again. :)

Comment: P.S. Also thanks for your time and consideration in putting your solution into a fiddle that I could fiddle with and learn. Nice touch.

Comment: The fiddle is pretty much standard around StackOverflow. It helps me, too, so that I know what I'm suggesting actually works. Glad to be of help!

Comment: is there a simple way to eliminate the right-most blank space with your solution? (I'm pretty new here... Do I need post this as a separate question?) Thanks.

Comment: No, follow-ups are fine. In a similar fashion, use `td:last-child { margin-right: 0; }`. The `td:last-child` selector obviously just selects the last table cell in a row.

Comment: Wow, that's slick. Worked right "out of the box." Thank you again for your time and consideration. I just enrolled in an 8-hour css course. (Honest). :)

Comment: Beginners are always welcome, just make sure your questions are up to par. I suggest you read this: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/